# In Tony Hillerman's People of Darkness, why do the Navajos accept Vines as a religious leader?

Tags: character-analysis

In Tony Hillerman's novel, *People of Darkness,* why have a group of Navajos, who followed some form of traditional Navajo religion, accepted B.J. Vines as their religious leader?

He's not only a white man, but a rich white man. Why would he be trusted that much? Is this plausible in some way, or is it a hole in the background of the story?